# jqgrid - column order changes with the client sort. How to prevent that?

Tags: jqgrid

I have a jqgrid which I save the order in the database. On loadComplete I put:

```
loadComplete: function(){
initorderColumn($("#Table"),2);
}
```

which is this function:

```
function initorderColumn($jqGrid,tabletype){
        $.ajax({
               url:"use/getorder",
               type:"get",
               dataType:    "json",
               async: false,
               data:{"type":tabletype},
               success: function(a) {
                   if(a.mycolumnorder){
                       var myorder=a.mycolumnorder.split(',');
                       $jqGrid.jqGrid("remapColumns", myorder,true);
                   }

    }


       });
```

The above function gets the order that user saved before. The issue is that when the user sort a column, the order changes. I want when the user sort a column, the order remains. Any idea?

Here is the jqgrid:

```
$("#Table").jqGrid({
            url: 'u.json,
            dataType: json,
            loadonce:true,
            colNames: msd.rise.columnDisplayNames,
            colModel: msd.rise.colModelDef,
            gridview: true,
            toppager: false,
            sortname: 'sd',
            sortorder: 'desc',
            sortable:true,
            loadComplete: function(){
            initorderColumn($("#Table"),2);
            var $self = $(this);
                if ($self.jqGrid("getGridParam", "datatype") === "json") {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $self.trigger("reloadGrid"); // Call to fix client-side sorting
                    }, 50);
                }
            }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It you don't want that the user be able to change the order of columns you should remove `sortable:true` option of jqGrid. Alternatively you can allow to do that but you can save new column order, which the user prefer to have, to the server. You need just to capture the changes of order.

jqGrid supports `jqGridRemapColumns` event which allow you to capture the changes of order in the grid:

```js
$("#Table").bind("jqGridRemapColumns", function () {
    // the order of columns is changed
    // you have to send the new column order to the server
});
```

One more problem is that it's probably better to save the column position by **names** of the column and not by position. I mean array of of indexes (`permutation` parameter) which required `remapColumns`. It would be probably practical to save the list of columns in database which the user like to see. One could get the list from the server and find the name in `colModel`. In the way one could convert the list of column names to the array of indexes which require `remapColumns` and only then one could call `remapColumns`.

The last remark: one could include the information about the column order in the main response from `url` used to fill the grid. So one would don't need to make separate Ajax call with `async: false` parameter. Inside of `beforeProcessing` callback one could compare the list of column order in the database with the current list of columns in `colModel` and to call `remapColumns` if it's required.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I removed sortable: true from the jqgrid, but still, when I sort a column, that column move forward.

Comment: @amandachaw: You are welcome! **How** you *sort* columns? The code which you posted don't have any column sorting. Your goals are unclear. Do you want to save the last column order in the database and restore it on the next visit of the page? In the case you should use `jqGridRemapColumns` like I described to detect the changes and posting the new order to the server. If you want to *prevent* changing the column position you have to identify the place of your code which allows the user to change the order. The only place in the code which you posted was `sortable: true`.

Comment: I already saved the columns order in the database. My issue is when I reload the grid with the new order and I try to do client sort (the one that jqgrid has by default) the column move forward and the order is discarded.

Comment: @amandachaw: Sorry, but all words from the last comment are very unspecific. You should post a clear example (the demo for example) which shows what you do exactly, how you load the data, in which format and so on. You should describe clear test case which can be used to reproduce the problem. I'm sure that if you would save **the names** of columns instead of the indexes (see my answer), than you should have no problems.

Comment: @amandachaw:  It's clear that you have some *implementation problems*, but you should be precise in the description. Till now you post the code with many clear bugs  like `dataType: json` instead of `datatype: "json"`, like `url: 'u.json,` which have syntax errors and so on. One can't help you to find the bug in your implementation if you post your implementation in so dirty form and just describes some scenarios which produce the problem. Sorry.